# Cadvisor "mountpoint for cpu not found"

Tags: docker, prometheus, monitoring, cadvisor

I ran Cadvisor with the below config but the container restarted!

```
cadvisor:
    image: google/cadvisor:v0.33.0
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:ro
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
      - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
    depends_on:
      - redis
    ...
```

**Error is:**

```
F0117 09:19:19.566897       1 cadvisor.go:152] Failed to create a Container Manager: mountpoint for cpu not found
F0117 09:19:20.741998       1 cadvisor.go:152] Failed to create a Container Manager: mountpoint for cpu not found
```

Comment: What if you switch the image to gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor?

Comment: @howaldoliverdev I try this image and solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your base image to
gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor